# How to securely erase a partition of a SSD

Tags: ssd, secure-erase

I know there are ways to securely erase a whole SSD with Ubuntu tools, but my usecase is to just erase a partition of the SSD, since I want to sell my old notebook and need to make sure that the recovery partition of the SSD is not deleted, so that the buyer has the possibility to reinstall the notebook (factory settings and OS).

Is this possible with Ubuntu tools or at all? If not, is probably Gparted the second-best option to just wipe the partition ? (There is no ultra-sensitivity data stored on the notebook)

Comment: I would recommend using encryption in the first place, if there is any possibility of exposing your sensitive data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how secure you want to keep the data you're deleting.

Secure from the average user: Delete the old partition, make a new one, install Ubuntu on the new one.

Secure from users with data-recovery experience: Do `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdXY bs=32M`, replacing "/dev/sdXY" with the main data partition of the drive. Once that finishes up, delete the old partition, make a new one, install Ubuntu on the new one.

Secure from just about anyone: Make a disk image of the SSD onto a big external hard drive, secure erase the whole SSD, repartition it, restore the recovery partition into wherever it goes, then install Ubuntu on the spare partition. Make sure you can still boot into the recovery partition when you do this. Note: On some weird systems, this has the potential to not allow you to boot into the recovery partition again, so be aware of that, and if you really need the recovery partition to work, maybe don't go this route.

Even more secure from just about anyone: Buy a new SSD, replace the old one with the new one, partition, format, restore the recovery partition, then install Ubuntu into a different partition. Again, this might mess up the recovery partition if your system is weird. However, with this option, if the recovery partition doesn't work when you move it, you can switch back to the old SSD and most likely be OK.

Extremely secure: Chuck the recovery partition, buy a new SSD, and install Ubuntu onto it.

Which option you use will depend on how sensitive the data that was on the system before was. Note that every file that was ever saved on the system could *potentially* be recoverable, so if you one time saved your master password to a plain-text file on your desktop, and then deleted it, you probably should buy a new SSD for good measure. They're not that expensive, but your Google account might be a serious loss. However, if you didn't ever save anything ultra-sensitive to the computer at any time, you're probably fine.

Comment: Don't forget about the over-provisioning area of an SSD. Is the data sensitive enough to worry if TRIM wipes it or not?